# Jquery toggel class

Tags: css, jquery-ui, accordion, addclass

I have a accordion menu which is developed by using the below script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('li.button a').click(function(e){
     $(this).addClass('active');

        /* Finding the drop down list that corresponds to the current section: */
        var dropDown = $(this).parent().next();

        /* Closing all other drop down sections, except the current one */
        $('.dropdown').not(dropDown).slideUp('100');
        dropDown.slideToggle('100');

        /* Preventing the default event (which would be to navigate the browser to the link's address) */
        e.preventDefault();     })      

});
```

I need to add the .active class when the menu is clicked so i have added addclass in jquery , it is adding the class but the problem is the class should be removed when the another menu is clicked. I tried even toggleclass also but didnt work.

And also I want the first li item to be opened by default when the page is opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this at the beginning of your function :

```
$('li.button a').click(function(e){
    $('li.button a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    ...
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks. One more thing how do I open the 1st list item by default when the page is loaded?

Comment: $(function() {
    $('li.button a:first').addClass('active');
})

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('li.button a').each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("active").addClass("no-active"); // your non active class
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li.button a').click(function(e){
     if($(this).hasClass('active')) // this line verifies if the actual clicked element is already active
         return false;  // you can return false or do another operation here

     $('li.button a.active').removeClass('active');

     $(this).addClass('active');

     /* Finding the drop down list that corresponds to the current section: */ 
        var dropDown = $(this).parent().next(); 

        /* Closing all other drop down sections, except the current one */ 
        $('.dropdown').not(dropDown).slideUp('100'); 
        dropDown.slideToggle('100'); 

        /* Preventing the default event (which would be to navigate the browser to the link's address) */ 
        e.preventDefault();     
})
```